# How to create a button that links to different URL using if-else statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a `button` on my single product page that links back to the different product catalog pages depending on the category it is under. I have already created a general `button` in my `function.php` file like this:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_button', 13);
    function woocommerce_single_product_summary_button() 
    {
        echo'<a class="back_button" href="http://jibabloom.com/product-category/mains/">BACK TO SHOPPING</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if(has_term( 'your-term', 'category')){
    //Button Code
}else if(has_term( 'other-term', 'category' )){
    //Different Button Code
}
```